# Normalizing Fasttext Pretrained Fasttext word embedding

Tags: nlp, normalize, fasttext

I am trying to normalize a fasttext word vector to another range so it can be combined with other data.

I first access the pretrained model like this:

```
fasttext.util.download_model('en', if_exists='ignore')  # English
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
```

I am then reducing the model a shorter vector length

```
fasttext.util.reduce_model(ft, 36)
```

In order to normalize I am trying to do something like the following

((value - current_min)/(current_max - current_min)) * (desired_max - desired_min) + desired_min

I was thinking I would just normalize the vectors as I needed them so I wasn't trying to normalize them all at once and then save off another big fasttext object, but in order to do this I need to find the current max and min values in the fasttext object? Is the best way to do this to iterate over every array in the object to find the max and min? I'm confused by what exactly a fasttext object is and the normal min() max() functions won't work on it.

Edit: Forgot to include my current best idea for finding the max and min

```
fasttext_words = ft.get_words()
max_num = 0
min_num = 0
for word in fasttext_words:
    temp_max = max(ft.get_word_vector(word))
    temp_min = min(ft.get_word_vector(word))
    if temp_max > max_num:
        max_num = temp_max
    if temp_min < min_num:
        min_num = temp_min
```

Comment: It appears by 'normalize' you mean to re-scale them somehow, but it's not clear why. This isn't usually necessary. And, in this context, 'normalize' will often mean "re-scale all vectors to be of equivalent unit (`1.0`) magnitude" – but your code is doing nothing resembling that. So, what exactly is your end-goal here? **Why** are you trying to change all the vectors in a way that's not typical? Why will this change make it more combinable with other data? What is that other data and what sort of combination are you attempting for what purpose?

Comment: (Concatenation rather than addition would be more typical for machine-learning purposes, and in that case such re-scaling and truncation-to-fewer-dimensions wouldn't be necessary or wise.)

Comment: I am attempting to do something similar to this paper: http://artelab.dista.uninsubria.it/res/research/papers/2018/2018-IEEESensorsLetters-Nawaz.pdf where they translate word vectors into pixel representations, so I am trying to rescale to 0,255. Are you saying that this formula: ((value - current_min)/(current_max - current_min)) * (desired_max - desired_min) + desired_min" would not accomplish that?

Comment: Thanks for the specific paper link! It's interesting, but I'm surprised that literally turning word-vectors into colors on the image is an efficient approach... I wouldn't have expected that to be necessary to feed things into a CNN, other than as a way to use an off-the-shelf image-only CNN. (And still, to combine multiple dimensions into color-squares of particular sizes seems like extra indirection compared to, say, making every dimension a grayscale pixel.)

Comment: That said, I suspect you'd want to perform your rescaling to **each dimension individually** - where your existing code fragment will look for the max/min values across all dimensions. And it might simplify things to have done a unit-normalization of all the vectors, first, so that they're all on the 'unit sphere'. Then you could assume every dimension's range is necessarily -1.0 to 1.0, which could be scaled to 0-255 fairly easily. But, it's unclear from the paper what process they used - did they release any code, or do you think the authors would respond to a request-for-clarification?

Comment: They have multiple papers on this topic, and I believe in one they explicitly stated they rescaled over all the values, I have been working my way through their github (https://github.com/artelab/Multi-modal-classification) but haven't found their rescaling piece yet.

Comment: I'm curious when you say " I wouldn't have expected that to be necessary to feed things into a CNN, other than as a way to use an off-the-shelf image-only CNN", are there CNN architectures that could take in multiple modalities naturally? I would be curious if you had a specific implementation or architecture in mind when you said that.

Comment: The main problem I have been having with this methodology (I believe) is that the word vectors taken from a word2vec or fasttext vectorization all seem to be very bunched up, so they produce very similar pixels on an image and so I believe a CNN isn't able to make meaningful distinctions between them. This was my motivation for trying out fasttext, to see if it behaved differently from word2vec, but it was  pretty much identical, if not more normally distributed

Comment: No specific architecture in mind, other than to note that RGB 0-255 values are a representational kludge, and the convolutions often geometric in how they mix nearby pixels – whereas the internal layers are using floating-point values, and there is no essential 'neighborly' relationship between any word-vector dimensions. (Dimension #1 is no more related to its neighbors #0 and #2, justifying their mixing into a shaded pixel alongside #3/#4/#5, than it is related to dimension #77 or #201 etc.) So shoehorning of one dense embedding into a specifically-pixelated & situated image seems odd, …

Comment: …at least compared to devising some hybrid architecture that uses image CNN for truly geometric pixelated data, and something else (maybe other kinds of comvolutions, or something else entirely) for word-vector data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bunched up". The usual negative-sampling of Word2Vec & FastText (which are so alike that most observations applying to one will apply to another) can lead to vectors that are a bit lopsided around the origin point, but the effect isn't too harmful to many applications, and can be explicitly corrected-for (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01417), and might also naturally disappear with many kinds of re-mapping for coordinates into 0-255 discrete positive values.

Comment: If you're seeing a problem different from the authors, on same or similar data, it's likely some aspect of their setup they haven't documented enough to reproduce. For example, other ways of mapping coordinates to 0-255 might try to make every value equally common. (That is: not a simple linear scale & shift, but a percentile bucketing so the top 1/255th has value 255, etc.) I have no idea if that's necessary or helpful for their method, but I didn't find their brief phrasing "normalized to assume values in the interval [0 . . . 255] with
respect to k" specific enough to rule that in or out.

Comment: Yeah bunched up isn't exactly a technical term... Very normally distributed I guess? Seems to have very few observations deviating very far from the mean, which winds up with a bunch of grey-ish color pixels as my visual words... It seems like I would need a way to make the visual words more "distinctive" which probably means diving into their code a lot more.

Comment: I have toyed around with the idea of converting my normal distribution of word vector values to more of a standard uniform one, but I'm very unsure of the efficacy of doing something like that

Comment: Really, if you trust the paper authors' resuts, and your data/needs as being similar enough it shold work, I'd prioritize clarifying what they have done. If they used typical word-vectors, without any special adjustments to change the usual distribution-of-coordinate values, and it worked, matching that (before improvising further improvements) should take priority.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to standardize the word vectors:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
num_instances, num_maxlen = X_train.shape
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, newshape=(num_instances, num_maxlen))

num_instances, num_maxlen = X_test.shape
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, newshape=(num_instances, num_maxlen))
```